# Why doesn't this code attempting to use Hamcrest's hasItems compile?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest, matcher

Why does this not compile, oh, what to do?

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.hasItems;

ArrayList<Integer> actual = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
actual.add(1);
expected.add(2);
assertThat(actual, hasItems(expected));
```

error copied from comment:

```
cannot find symbol method assertThat(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>, org.hamcreset.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>>>)
```

Answer (score 55):

Just ran into this post trying to fix it for myself. Gave me just enough information to work it out.

You can give the compiler just enough to persuade it to compile by casting the return value from hasItems to a (raw) Matcher, eg:

```
ArrayList<Integer> actual = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
actual.add(1);
expected.add(2);
assertThat(actual, (Matcher) hasItems(expected));
```

Just in case anybody else is still suffering ...

Edit to add:
In spite of the up votes, this answer is wrong, as Arend points out below. The *correct* answer is to turn the expected into an array of Integers, as hamcrest is expecting:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> actual = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    actual.add(1);
    expected.add(2);
    assertThat(actual, hasItems(expected.toArray(new Integer[expected.size()])));
```

Comment: I haven't tested this answer since I long ago have lost this source code (moved companies twice), but I gave you a thumb up for resurrecting this.

Comment: Good tip. Seems the only "straightforward" way to use assertThat() with any collection matcher since Hamcrest changed their collection matcher generics to <? extends T> instead of just <T> ..

Comment: I wished `hasItems` also matched the order. Which it seems like it does not.

Comment: `hasItems` is used to assert that the collection has the items in question, it does not require that it has no other items or the order.

You probably want to look at `contains`, which ensures that the collection has all of the supplied items, in order, and nothing else.

Comment: This is **WRONG**. This answer checks if `actual` contains the List `expected`, not if `actual` contains the elements of the List `expected`. Try it with `expected.add(1)` instead: This code will never pass. There's a very good reason for the compiler error. Not a good idea to just suppress it with a cast.

Comment: Yeees, which given I went on and got the test passing is confusing, to say the least.

The _correct_ answer, is:

    ArrayList<Integer> actual = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    actual.add(1);
    expected.add(2);
    assertThat(actual, hasItems(expected.toArray(new  Integer[expected.size()])));

Comment: This post is a disaster. Please update it or remove it.

Comment: How so? The edited answer is as correct now as it was when it was edited.

Answer (score 22):

hasItems checks that a collection contains some items, not that 2 collections are equal, just use the normal equality assertions for that. So either assertEquals(a, b) or using assertThat

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;

ArrayList<Integer> actual = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
actual.add(1);
expected.add(2);
assertThat(actual, is(expected));
```

Alternatively, use the contains Matcher, which checks that an Iterable contains items in a specific order

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;

ArrayList<Integer> actual = new ArrayList<Integer>();
actual.add(1);
actual.add(2);
assertThat(actual, contains(1, 2)); // passes
assertThat(actual, contains(3, 4)); // fails
```

If you don't care about the order use `containsInAnyOrder` instead.

Answer (score 12):

You are comparing `ArrayList<Integer>` with `int`. The correct comparison is:

```
...
assertThat(actual, hasItem(2));
```

-- Edit --

I'm sorry, I've read it wrong. Anyway, the signature of `hasItems` you want is:

```
public static <T> org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<T>> hasItems(T... elements)
```

i.e., it accepts a variable number of arguments. I'm not sure if an `ArrayList<T>` is compatible, just guessing here. Try sending each item from the expected list interspersed by comma.

```
assertThat(actual, hasItems(2,4,1,5,6));
```

-- Edit 2 --

Just pasting here my comment, there is an equivalent expression for what you want, without using Hamcrest:

```
assertTrue(actual.containsAll(expected));
```

Comment: I'm comparing multiple items. (hasItems, not hasItem)

Comment: So, hamcrest simply does not support comparing two collections?

(I don't have an actual list of items, I'm building the list of numbers from 0 to 999 I must compare collections).

Comment: I cannot answer that for you, I'm telling this based on the documentation. But there is a simpler way to do what you want... use assertTrue(actual.containsAll(expected)).

Comment: it's simpler, but when this assert fails you get a very cryptic error messages, which is less helpful than the error message that I imagine hasItems outputs.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
assertThat(actual, hasItems(expected.toArray(new Integer[0])));
```

to satisfy the matcher signature. No Eclipse around, so this might not work.

Answer (score 2):

That error message looks like one produced by the javac compiler. I've found in the past that code written using hamcrest just won't compile under javac. The same code will compile fine under, say, the Eclipse compiler.

I think Hamcrest's generics are exercising corner cases in generics that javac can't deal with.

Comment: Wow, interesting. So you're saying the above code is legitimate java code?

Comment: No, I'm saying that javac sometimes rejects legitimate java code, and hamcrest is a common cause of it.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across the same problem and the following trick worked for me:

- use `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItems`
- have the hamcrest library before junit in classpath (build path -> order and export)

Answer (score 2):

You can get this error if you try to replace jUnit's hamcrest with a newer version. For example, using junit-dep together with hamcrest 1.3 requires that use assertThat from hamcrest instead of jUnit.

So the solution is to use

`import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;`

instead of

`import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;`

Answer (score 1):

For these cases when code does compile in Eclipse but javac shows errors please do help hamcrest by providing explicitly type parameter e.g.
Matchers.hasItem()

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> expected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
expected.add(1);
expected.add(2);
hasItems(expected);
```

hasItems(T..t) is being expanded by the compiler to:

```
hasItems(new ArrayList<Integer>[]{expected});
```

You are passing a single element array containing an ArrayList.  If you change the ArrayList to an Array, then your code will work.

```
Integer[] expected = new Integer[]{1, 2};
hasItems(expected);
```

This will be expanded to:

```
hasItems(1, 2);
```