# Why does this hamcrest matcher work in eclipse but not outside?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, junit, hamcrest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hamcrest's hasItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092981/hamcrests-hasitems)

I've written a test using a hamcrest matcher that looks like:

```
@Test
public void testGenericsIsEmpty() {
    List<String> myStrings = new LinkedList<String>();
    assertThat((Collection)myStrings,is(empty()));
}
```

This works when I compile in Eclipse, but not outside of Eclipse. My maven project uses the eclipse compiler, so it compiles outside of Eclipse when using maven, but if I use the standard java compiler, it doesn't compile.

I get the error message

*cannot find symbol method assertThat(java.util.Collection,org.hamcrest.Matcher>)*

I'm using junit 4.10 and hamcrest 1.3.RC2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092981/hamcrests-hasitems

Comment: Yep, that was it. This should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Have you already tried this:

```
assertThat(myString, is(Matchers.<String>empty()));
```