# Assert Array Equals method in Testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium-ios

I have a list of arrays {1,2,3}. 
and I have a xpath. what I actually need is with the xpath the output will be any of the array either 1 or 2 or 3. I want to assert the value and pass the test using testng.

Is there any possibility to do something like that.

Comment: I think you can use [hamcrest](http://openwritings.net/content/public/excerpt/using-hamcrest-testng) with TestNG. See example from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092981/hamcrests-hasitems)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I got your question correctly. But if you want to compare the text in an element with given values, you can save these three elements in a list and use `contains`

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("1");
arrayList.add("2");
arrayList.add("3");

Assert.assertTrue(arrayList.contains(YourElement.getText()));
```