# JUnit - Comparing Arrays of objects

Tags: java, junit

I have a test that is intended to test the contents of an Array of objects (a set of rules that use a Rule wrapper class) that get returned from a DB:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "rule_1",
        description: "this rule will check something",
    },
]


    @Test
public void testQueryRules() throws IOException {

    final List<Rule> rules = ruleDB.queryRules();
    final String expectedRuleId = "1";
    final String expectedName = "rule_1";
    final String expectedDescription = "this rule will check something";

    final Rule rule = new Rule(expectedRuleId, expectedName, expectedDescription);
    final List<Rule> expectedRules = new ArrayList<Rule>();
    expectedRules.add(rule);

    expectedRules.forEach(expectedRule -> {
        System.out.println("RULE ID " + expectedRule.getRuleId());
        System.out.println("RULE NAME " + expectedRule.getRuleName());
        System.out.println("RULE DESCRIPTION " + expectedRule.getDescription());
    });

    rules.forEach(actualRule -> {
        System.out.println("ACTUAL RULE ID " + actualRule.getRuleId());
        System.out.println("ACTUAL RULE NAME " + actualRule.getRuleName());
        System.out.println("ACTUAL DESCRIPTION " + actualRule.getDescription());
    });

    System.out.println("MATCHED " + Arrays.deepEquals(expectedRules.toArray(), rules.toArray()));
    System.out.println("MATCHED AGAIN " + Arrays.equals(expectedRules.toArray(), rules.toArray()));

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(expectedRules.toArray(), rules.toArray());
}
```

As you can see, I've tried using `Arrays.equals()`, as well as `Arrays.deepEquals()`, and `assertArrayEquals()`. None of those seem to give a successful test even though the output of both the expected and actual is the same:

EXPECTED:

```
RULE ID: 1
RULE NAME: "rule 1",
RULE DESCRIPTION: "this rule will check something",
```

ACTUAL:

```
ACTUAL RULE ID: 1
ACTUAL RULE NAME: "rule 1",
ACTUAL RULE DESCRIPTION: "this rule will check something"
```

What is the standard way to test arrays of objects in Java? It seems like its failing because the pointer reference is different even though the contents is the same.

Comment: You can try to use a Set : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313229/junit-4-compare-collections

Comment: What is `Rule`? Does it override `equals()`?

Comment: To complete @Oleg comment, this is not because all attributes of 2 objects are equal that these 2 objects are also equal. Overwrite equals.

Comment: @Oleg that's exactly what it didn't do. My Rule wrapper class didn't override equals. If you add this as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as correct.

Comment: @snakespan That's OK, thanks. I don't do that anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html) for that. Especially its `usingFieldByFieldElementComparator`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class MyTests {
    static class Rule {
        final String id;
        final String name;
        final String description;

        Rule(String id, String name, String description) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
        }

        // no equals, no hashCode
    }

    @Test
    void rulesShouldEqual_whenTheirPropertiesEqual() {
        Rule actualRule1 = new Rule("id1", "name1", "description1");
        Rule actualRule2 = new Rule("id2", "name2", "description2");
        List<Rule> actual = Arrays.asList(actualRule1, actualRule2);

        Assertions.assertThat(actual).usingFieldByFieldElementComparator().containsExactly(
                new Rule("id1", "name1", "description1"),
                new Rule("id2", "name2", "description2"));
    }
}
```