# JUnit: Asserting for equality of collections with parameterized type - arrays

Tags: java, generics, junit, guava

I am trying to assert for equality the following collections:

```
String[] arr1= new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
Collection<String[]> coll1= Arrays.asList(arr1, arr1);

String[] arr2 = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
Collection<String[]> coll2 = Arrays.asList(arr2, arr2);

assertEquals(coll1, coll2);
```

however, I got a result opposite to the expected - an assertion error. The problem is that the arrays are checked for equality with `Object.equals()` method which actually checks the reference of the arrays which are clearly different.

Is there any handy method I can use from JUnit or Guava to overcome this problem?

EDIT: Notice that I want to compare **the Collection** objects, **not the arrays** itself.

Comment: Try to use `assertArrayEquals` http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object[])

Comment: One more good reason to avoid arrays and use collections instead.

Comment: Could assert that each entry in the arrays are equal to each other?

Comment: I want to assert the Collection objects, not the arrays.

Comment: Possible workaround: wrap `Collection` class and override `equals` function. Just idea

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086691/collectionassert-in-junit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where Hamcrest comes to the rescque. Here is the javadoc [link](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/). I would suggest using [IsArrayContainingInOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsArrayContainingInOrder.html)

So...

```
assertThat(coll1, IsArrayContainingInOrder.arrayContaining(coll2));
```

sorry, the above would work for the arrays but the below will work for the collections...

```
assertThat(coll1, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains(coll2.toArray()));
```

This uses [IsIterableContainingInOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIterableContainingInOrder.html)

FYI, I have found using Hamcrest matchers so elegant that I rarely if ever use non-Hamcrest testing. So all my tests read like

```
assertThat(myValue, is(true));
assertThat(myValue, equalTo("something"));
assertThat(myList, IsIterableContainingInAnyOrder.containsInAnyOrder(first, second, third));
```

Off soap box.

Comment: This looks interesting, but it seems these definitions are not included in the hamcrest dependency of JUnit 4.10.

Comment: True. They come in `hamcrest-all`. see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all/1.3. If you are using 4.10 of JUnit this can cause some conflicts with Hamcrest (because it includes SOME Hamcrest classes). I recommend updating to JUnit 4.11 which does not have this issue.

Comment: Here is a discussion of Hamcrest with JUnit. Again remember that JUnit 4.11 has resolved this issue. https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/issues/detail?id=166

Comment: That's it. Even though I should call toArray() of the second collection, I like the solution. It is readable and concise. I have also very nice output when the assertion fails.

Comment: Yeah, the output on failure is one of the reasons I really prefer Hamcrest. I know the `toArray` thing is a bit annoying but still works very well. Cheers.

Comment: it seems that the call toArray() is not only annoying but it could be problematic since the collections can be null. Any ideas?

Comment: General rule would be to NEVER use / allow `null` for a collection but instead use empty collections. I follow this rule. Also, since the argument being passed to the `Matcher` is your `expected` value, it should never be null. If you are expecting null use `CoreMatchers.nullValue()`

Comment: Yes, I agree - the billion dollar mistake... thanks, I think I am going to change the contract.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Arrays#deepEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29):

```
boolean isSameArrayContent = Arrays.deepEquals(coll1.toArray(), coll2.toArray());
assertTrue(isSameContent);
```

Comment: The OP doesn't asked for comparing arrays.

Comment: If you call arrays by collections, I have nothing to say to you.

Comment: Firstly you say one then second, I don't understand you point, after that downvoting my answer. Converting is another thing it could be buggy and needs testing separately.

Comment: +1: I prefer the solution of John B since it is more readable in my opinion. However, your solution doesn't introduce an additional dependency which is a plus.