# Unit testing of linkedlist

Tags: java, junit, linked-list

Iterate through the linkedlist is like this: -

```
    LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> itr = ll.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        int val = itr.next();
    }
```

Question is how to unit test(eg: if elements are 1, 2, 3, 4 in sequence is the unit test case, or example a sortLinkedList function, etc.) such collections where only way to loop through them is through Iterator ?
Also please refrain from giving solutions that involve Guava.

Comment: what do you mean by - *add new function*?

Comment: sorry for confusion, edited.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the unit test?  Are you testing a LinkedList implementation?

Comment: seems that he wants to implement sort using tdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
Iterator<Integer> itr = ll.iterator();

int i = 0;
int[] seq = {1, 2, 3, 4};

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    int val = itr.next();
    assertEquals(seq[i], val);
    i++;
}
```

Or even simpler, use an enhanced for loop:

```
LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();

int i = 0;
int[] seq = {1, 2, 3, 4};

for (Integer val : ll) {
    assertEquals(seq[i], val);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilites.
You won't get around creating an object that you can assert like a string or a collection. assert.

To do this you can build a helper function that you can reuse in your tests.

Check this [post for asserting collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086691/collectionassert-in-junit).