# How to properly unit test a property change?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I have this test:

```
@Test
public void UpdateAllFooDatesToOneDayBeforeProvidedDate_TodaysDateAndFooDate_UpdatedDates() {
    // arrange
    List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    Date barDate = today;
    Foo foo1 = setupFoo();
    Foo foo2 = setupFoo();
    foos.add(foo1);
    foos.add(foo2);
    foo1.setValidTo(dateUtil.adjustDaysOfDate(today, 5));
    foo2.setValidTo(dateUtil.adjustDaysOfDate(today, 8));

    // act
    modifyDates.updateAllFooDatesToOneDayBeforeProvidedDate(barDate, foos);

    // assert
    assertThat(foos, hasItems(...?)); //I don't know how to assert this
}
```

updateAllFooDatesToOneDayBeforeProvidedDate(Date, List) simply *changes a date property of all Foos to the day before barDate*.

I am trying to use Hamcrest to help me assert that the list has been updated, but I can't really get it to work.

Should I simply use foos.get(n).getDate() and assert on those?

**What is the preferred way of asserting that the date property of the elements in foos has been updated properly?**

Edit: Typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aren't you making it hard on yourself here? Why not just iterate over the collection and assert for each element?

```
for ( Foo foo : foos ) { assertThat( foo.getDate() , equalTo( barDate ) ); }
```

Cheers,

Comment: Yes I see. Thanks Anders! It was just that I snowed in on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086691/collectionassert-in-junit) question that led me to believe that there was a more "Hamcresty" way of doing this. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: You could user the `array()` matcher family and extract your dates using eg. [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) - if your actual use case is more complex than above, this might be more expressive...

Comment: Good idea! However, I think for my case it is not much more complex than the code in my OP apart from that I assert a date in the past (-1 day). I think I will go with the iteration (or simply get() if there is only one assert) for this one.