# How do Hamcrest's hasItems, contains and containsInAnyOrder differ?

Tags: hamcrest

Hamcrest provides a number of matchers for asserting the contents of a collection. All of these cases pass:

```
Collection<String> c = ImmutableList.of("one", "two", "three");
assertThat(c, hasItems("one", "two", "three");
assertThat(c, contains("one", "two", "three");
assertThat(c, containsInAnyOrder("one", "two", "three");
```

How do `hasItems`, `contains` and `containsInAnyOrder` differ?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

[`hasItems` checks](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasItems%28T...%29):

> consecutive passes over the examined Iterable yield at least one item that is equal to the corresponding item from the specified `items`.

That is, it makes sure that the collections contains *at least* these items, *in any order*. So,

```
assertThat(c, hasItems("one", "two"));
```

would also pass, with the extra item being ignored. And:

```
assertThat(c, hasItems("three", "two", "one"));
```

would also pass.

[`contains` checks](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains%28E...%29):

> a single pass over the examined `Iterable` yields a series of items, each logically equal to the corresponding item in the specified items. For a positive match, the examined iterable must be of the same length as the number of specified items.

So it makes sure that the collection contains *exactly* these items:

```
assertThat(c, contains("one", "two")); // Fails
```

This would fail, as the leftover `"three"` is not matched.

```
assertThat(c, contains("three", "two", "one")); // Fails
```

This fails because the corresponding items don't match.

Another related matcher, `containsInAnyOrder`, [checks](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder%28T...%29) that exactly those items are present, but in any order:

> Creates an order agnostic matcher for `Iterables` that matches when a single pass over the examined `Iterable` yields a series of items, each logically equal to one item anywhere in the specified items.

A test with a missing item fails:

```
assertThat(c, containsInAnyOrder("one", "two")); // Fails
```

But all items in a different order will pass:

```
assertThat(c, containsInAnyOrder("three", "two", "one"));
```

Comment: I would rename contains into consistsOf

Comment: `contains` is a MASSIVE misnomer. I would have expected that `contains` does the same as `Collection#contains`.

Comment: [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) calls this method [`containsExactly`](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/ObjectEnumerableAssert.html#containsExactly%28ELEMENT...%29),  which may also help reduce surprise.

Comment: what if i want to use containsInAnyOrder, but the lists contains duplicates? e.g i want to check, if List contains exact elements, but they have duplicates - in that case containsAnyOrder("three","three","one") would holds true, even if tested list only has ("three,"one") elements. How to deal with this?

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov consistsOfOrdered